# Receive android intent in Chrome 57: any documentation?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

[According to this Chromium blog post](https://blog.chromium.org/2017/02/chrome-57-beta-css-grid-layout-improved.html) we should now be able to receive intents in Chrome for Android:

> "Progressive Web Apps [..] will be able to receive incoming intents
>   from other apps."

Except it looks like this is undocumented? There is not a single link to be found in the post and a quick Google didn't help me either.

Anyone know where to find the docs?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't mean anything fancy, just that the manifest will include an intent filter for the app's URL.

Here's a snippet from https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/android/webapk/shell_apk/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
    <data android:scheme="{{{scope_url_scheme}}}"
          android:host="{{{scope_url_host}}}"
          android:pathPrefix="{{{scope_url_path}}}"></data>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: That looks like it's meant to catch an intent *from* chrome *in* another app. That's been around for a while. According to the blog I mentioned we should be able to do it the other way around: "Progressive Web Apps [..] will be able to receive incoming intents from other apps." - So we should be able to define an intent filter in the web app and *receive* those intents *in chrome*

Comment: I think the point is that the PWA does define an intent filter, namely for the app's URL, but you can't customize it. And this file is less than a year old.

Comment: Ok then the wording is just super weird. It says "receive an intent", not "automagically open your PWA when someone clicks on a link to your url". I think I also read somewhere that you could deeplink into the PWA so how would that work for single page web apps (which, to my knowledge, means most of them)?

Comment: What I mean is: shouldn't the PWA have some kind of way to at least "receive" (access) the intent? Like, with addEventListener or something?